# Extend Video Strip in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In older versions of Blender I was able to extend a video strip in VSE using the triangle at the right end. In this case the last image stayed visible. But in the current Version, this is no longer the case. But for me, that was a nice feature. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The freeze frame at either the start or end of a strip only occurs when you reach the limit of the source media. You can fake this by adding a Hard Cut using shift-k. Then drag the strip end as usual but now it will be shaded grey and show only a still frame. If it flickers then click the Refresh Sequencer button at the bottom of the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that feature. But I would solve that by just rendering out the last image and then save it. That image I would put at the end of the video sequence. But there might be an addon for this.

Comment: That's my current work around. But before it was just much easier.

Comment: I use that feature a lot with my current version 2.77a, a version I'm quite happy with.  I usually avoid upgrades until the bugs are ironed out.