# How to repeat a single frame?

Tags: edit-mode

I see a lot about repeating an animation sequence, but my issue is much simpler.

I'm using the video editor to make a very simple video, just a slide show really. I have a video of a person giving a talk and I'm just overlaying a set of slides to illustrate her talk. I've got that working very well.

The original video of the talk ends abruptly at the end of her last sentence. I'd like to fix that by extending the last frame for a few seconds and then fading to black. So my question is very simple, but I don't see it answered anywhere:

How do I get the last frame of a video to repeat for a few seconds?

==============================

I tried the technique suggested in the comment by @Edgel3D, but it didn't work. I'm saying that here so I can attach a picture of what happened:

[image]

The video strip in channel 2 used to be the same length as the audio strip in channel 1 at 11,575 frames. I pulled out the end handle on channel 2, which seems to have expanded it to either 11,771 frames or 11,772, depending on which number in the image above I should believe. But when I play it, after frame 11,575 the video window goes to a black and grey checkerboard pattern. The last frame is not being repeated. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the original video's strip, there are two handles, one at each end.  Simply pull the right side's end out with the mouse button. (Left button I think) This will extend that last frame out for as many frames as you like.  You can use this extension to fade the scene out to black by keyframing the strip's opacity.  Take some abience audio from another part, copy and lay that with the silent extension, fade that out in sync with the video's fade.

Comment: @Edgel3D - Please see my edit to the question to see what happened when I tried what you suggested.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69679/extend-video-strip-in-vse    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/how-do-i-create-a-freeze-frame-effect-with-video-editing  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/fastest-way-to-keep-the-last-frame-of-a-clip-persistent/10751#10751

Comment: Okay, looks like I was way wrong that this would be simple. Those three links describe methods that either don't work or are complex and explained in jargon I don't understand. One gives a link to the manual, and the link doesn't work. Actually, there was a simple method suggested, to render the last frame and then insert it at the end. But the color of the rendered image is washed out, so it makes an ugly transition. I'm going to give up for now and just let the slide show end on that last frame. If dragging out that right-hand handle used to work, it's really too bad that's been disabled!

Comment: It sounds like you've 'stretched' the part of the strip that's already black.

What you have to do is slide the timeline cursor to the last frame(s) that gives you the right image.  Snip it there with SHIFT-K, select the right hand segment and delete it.  Try stretching the new end-handle.  Also make sure the frame range you've got set below will acomodate the frames you're trying to render after the stretch.  If that doesn't work. could it be the format or codecs of the film you've imported?  I mostly convert  to avi format first when the vse acts up with some mp4's etc.

Comment: Oh, duh! Of course, how dumb of me. I actually did notice the video content ended a couple of frames before the end of the strip, so of course the last couple of frames were black, and what I did was a freeze frame of that! So your method did work. Thanks for the shift-K trick that allowed me to discard those black frames and freeze the one I wanted. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it, which will be good for people coming here in the future. (Also, of the three links above, at least one said this technique no longer works, which apparently is not correct.)

Comment: Mystery solved, that's what matters. :)  Will redo the comments as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original video's strip, there are two handles, one at each end. Simply pull the right side's end out with the mouse button. (Left button I think)

Beware of any faulty or black frames that might be present at the end.
These can be sliced off with SHIFT-K.  Delete those.

Once the very end frame is valid video pull the handle to the right and this will extend that last frame out for as many frames as you like. You can use this extension to fade the scene out to black by keyframing the strip's opacity.

Take some abience audio from another part, copy and lay that with the silent extension, fade that out over the same frames as your inserted fade to black.

You can copy/paste the original audio strip, into a free strip and if I remember rightly, you might also be able to duplicate it with SH-D and simply drag the copy up to a free strip.  Once the copy is established, it can be sliced up to extract whatever you want, lay it where it's needed.